# Create VPN conststing of two nodes using Easy-OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I'd like to construct OpenVPN network consisting ow two nodes, so you connect to one node, but iteraction with internet comes from another node.

```
Client -> 1st OpenVPN instance -> 2nd OpenVPN instance -> Internet.
```

Is it possible to do using EasyOpenVPN package?

I don't like to delve into manual openvpn config.

Comment: It's called Split Tunneling, Some VPN Providers allow this...Search --> PIA Spilt Tunneling.

Comment: Sorry I'm not more clear, that's really not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: easy-openvpn is  an ubuntu snap package